# xml schema version always null and sequence attribute not reading

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using this http://ws.apache.org/commons/XmlSchema/, in my android project. I'm iterating through an XML schema which has a version such as the following,

```
<xs:schema version="4.0.2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:p="http://test.com/schema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" >

XmlSchemaCollection schemaCol = new XmlSchemaCollection();
XmlSchema xmlSchema           = schemaCol.read(new StreamSource(is), null);
String version                = xmlSchema.getVersion();
```

But when look at `version` it's always null.

I am also trying to extract a custom attribute that is embedded in a 'sequence' tag.

```
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" p:customattrib="true">
```

Can someone tell me how to extract from 'version' and the custom attribute from the XML document.

Comment: how did you get null?

Comment: @blackbelt edited my answer! any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am sorry, I never used it, but are you sure that you can add arbitrates  attributes to the `xs:schema` ? Is not usually the attribute version contained in `<?xml `?

Comment: @blackbelt yeah that's what I was wondering...suppose I move it to 

<?xml version="4.0.2" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema version="4.0.2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" >

how would I read it?

Comment: I will try to remove the attribute from `xs:schema`, put it in the `<?xml ` and try to read the attribute the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to edit the source, there was no other way.

Comment: Dang, I was writing the answer while debugging the library and I did not see you had already answered this a few minutes ago... :/

Comment: @matiash haha....show me the actual code to extract the attribute, and I'll give you the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

From taking a look at the way this library parses XML schemas, it looks like this information is not kept. For example, the `sequence` element is parsed as such:

```
    XmlSchemaSequence sequence = new XmlSchemaSequence();

    // handle min and max occurences
    sequence.setMinOccurs(getMinOccurs(sequenceEl));
    sequence.setMaxOccurs(getMaxOccurs(sequenceEl));

    for (Element el = XDOMUtil.getFirstChildElementNS(sequenceEl, XmlSchema.SCHEMA_NS);
         el != null;
         el = XDOMUtil.getNextSiblingElementNS(el, XmlSchema.SCHEMA_NS)) {
         ...
```

Only the `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` attributes are read, if present, and then it moves to the child nodes. Although you can take a peek at `sequenceEl` and `customattrib` is indeed there, its value is not copied into the `XmlSchemaSequence` object.

---

If modifying the library is an option, then you could hardwire `SchemaBuilder.handleSequence()` to read it, something like:

```
String customAttrib = sequenceEl.getAttribute("customattrib");
```

Or, probably much better, add a new member to `XmlSchemaObject`, say

```
public Map<String, String> extraAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And then read all custom attributes there, like this:

```
NamedNodeMap attributes = sequenceEl.getAttributes();
for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node attNode = attributes.item(i);
    sequence.extraAttributes.put(attNode.getLocalName(), attNode.getNodeValue());
}
```

And similarly in `handleXmlSchemaElement()` to get the `version` attribute there. Although for this change to be more or less reasonable, this code should be invoked from *all* the `handle<X>` methods in `SchemaBuilder`.

---

Another option, if modifying the *schema* itself is feasible, would be to use XSD annotations instead of custom attributes. Annotations seem to be properly read by this framework.